# Google Slides API REST Resources "Cropped Image" without contentURL?

Tags: json, image, rest, export, google-slides-api

while trying to export whole presentations of Google Slides with the Google Slides API i'm facing a problem with the export of "cropped images".

If your're using the "crop image" functionality in the Google Slides Editor, to get  e.g. a "ROUND_RECTANGLE" appearance for the image, also the type of the page element switches in the exporting REST Resource from "image" to "shape".

So there won't be no more a field in the exported JSON for the contentURL like in the image type and thus it seems not to be possible to load the origin or the "cropped" image file.

Maybe someone knows an alternate workaround or solving for this problem?

I would be pleased if somebody could help me. But i'm also interested in informations why it maybe won't work actually.

Have a nice day!

Hannes

Comment: That looks like a bug. Mind reporting it [here](https://developers.google.com/slides/support#bugs)?

Comment: Hmm, that sounds like a really simple recommendation. 
Now, why didn't I think of that? Thx ...